# Retrofit API call returns null

Tags: android, json, kotlin, retrofit

Here is the API/JSON data I am trying to use: https://pogoapi.net/api/v1/pokemon_names.json

The problem is that when I try and parse the JSON response null is only returned.

Models:

```
data class ListOfReleasedPokemon(
    val releasedPokemon: List<PokemonResponse>
)

data class PokemonResponse(
    val pokemonMap: Map<String, ReleasedPokemonModel>
)

data class ReleasedPokemonModel(
    val id: Int,
    val name: String
)
```

API call:

```
interface PogoApi {
    @GET("released_pokemon.json")
    suspend fun getReleasedPokemon(): ListOfReleasedPokemon
}
```

App Module:

```
@Module
@InstallIn(SingletonComponent::class)
object AppModule {
    @Singleton
    @Provides
    fun providePokemonRepository(
        pogoApi: PogoApi
    ) = PokemonRepository(pogoApi)

    @Singleton
    @Provides
    fun providePogoApi(): PogoApi{
//        val gson = GsonBuilder()
//            .registerTypeAdapter(ReleasedPokemonModel::class.java, JsonDeserializer())
//            .create()
        return Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl(POGO_API_BASE_URL)
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
            .build()
            .create(PogoApi::class.java)
    }
}
```

Repository(**Where the error is found**):

```
@ActivityScoped
class PokemonRepository @Inject constructor(
    private val pogoApi: PogoApi
){
    suspend fun getReleasedPokemonList(): Resource<ListOfReleasedPokemon> {
        val response = try{
            pogoApi.getReleasedPokemon()
//          Returns null
        } catch(e: IOException){
            return Resource.Error("Please check your internet connection")
        } catch(e: HttpException){
            return Resource.Error("Unexpected response")
        }
        Log.d("MainActivity", "GetPokemonReleasedList Run with no errors")
        return Resource.Success(data = response)
    }
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: I'm seeing the list item in the API is actually not a list, it's a regular object and contains other objects inside. Maybe you should review your data response.

Comment: Is there a way I could parse this if its in this format?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oh, I just noticed now that you seem to have a question related to this Json parser.

Well in this comment I will guide you in detail with this project of yours.
Because the previous question you asked only how to parse Json with undefined key.

First, create a custom Json Deserializer. Because here your data api has an undefined key. Here I will create 1 gson with custom Json Deserializer. As follows:

*PokemonResponse*

```
data class PokemonResponse(
    val pokemonMap: List<StringReleasedPokemonModel>
)

data class ReleasedPokemonModel(
    val id: Int,
    val name: String
)
```

*GsonHelper.kt*

```
object GsonHelper {
    fun create(): Gson = GsonBuilder().apply {
        registerTypeAdapter(PokemonResponse::class.java, PokemonType())
        setLenient()
    }.create()

    private class PokemonType : JsonDeserializer<PokemonResponse> {
        override fun deserialize(
            json: JsonElement?,
            typeOfT: Type?,
            context: JsonDeserializationContext?
        ): PokemonResponse {
            val list = mutableListOf<ReleasedPokemonModel>()
            // Get your all key
            val keys = json?.asJsonObject?.keySet()
            keys?.forEach { key ->
                // Get your item with key
                val item = Gson().fromJson<ReleasedPokemonModel>(
                    json.asJsonObject[key],
                    object : TypeToken<ReleasedPokemonModel>() {}.type
                )
                list.add(item)
            }
            return PokemonResponse(list)
        }
    }
}
```

Next, Provide this Gson to your Dagger or Hilt.

*AppModule.kt*

```
@Module
@InstallIn(SingletonComponent::class)
object AppModule {

    @Provides
    fun provideGson(): Gson = GsonHelper.create()
    ...
}
```

And then you modify your `addConverterFactory` as follows:

*AppModule.kt*

```
@Module
@InstallIn(SingletonComponent::class)
object AppModule {

    @Provides
    fun provideGson(): Gson = GsonHelper.create()

    @Singleton
    @Provides
    fun providePogoApi(gson: Gson): PogoApi = Retrofit.Builder()
        .baseUrl(POGO_API_BASE_URL)
        .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create(gson))
        .build()
        .create(PogoApi::class.java)
}
```

In `PogoApi`, change the return type of `getReleasedPokemon()` to `PokemonResponse`.

```
interface PogoApi {
    @GET("released_pokemon.json")
    suspend fun getReleasedPokemon(): PokemonResponse
}
```

And finally, in your repository, edit the following:

*PokemonRepository.kt*

```
@ActivityScoped
class PokemonRepository @Inject constructor(
    private val pogoApi: PogoApi
){
    suspend fun getReleasedPokemonList(): Resource<PokemonResponse> = try {
        val response = pogoApi.getReleasedPokemon()
        Log.d("MainActivity", "list: ${response}")
        Resource.Success(data = response)
    } catch(e: IOException){
        Resource.Error("Please check your internet connection")
    } catch(e: HttpException){
        Resource.Error("Unexpected response")
    }
}
```